# Magento issue with email charset

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7

I have a little issue. I'm using to send mail in my custom module this piece of code:

```
$content = 'Wiadomość testowa ąśźć';

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName($name);
        $mail->setToEmail($email);
        $mail->setBody($content);
        $mail->setSubject($subject);
        $mail->setFromEmail('test@test.com');
        $mail->setFromName("Test");
        $mail->setType('html');

        try {
            $mail->send();
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('success',Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Your request has been sent'));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('error',Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Unable to send email.'));
        }
```

How can I set utf-8 charset before sending email in magento mail function. ?
I get email with no utf-8 charset in email body.

**SOLVED**
I created sendZendMail function in helper.
I used this function, instead `Magento core/email`:

```
public function sendZendMail($name,$email,$subject,$content){
    $mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($content);
    $mail->setFrom('your@frommail.com');
    $mail->addTo($email, 'No reply');
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    try {
        $mail->send();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Mail was sucessfully send.');
    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email.');
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

kristoff, I had the same issue before with Portuguese, which also has special characters. I've sorted it out by using the function htmlentities() for accented words. The Zend Mail Object is a bit retarded. I hope it helps.